# In iOS7, cell.selectedBackgroundView is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Working on converting an iOS6 app to iOS7, and they are using this to setup a grouped tableview style.

```
    cell.backgroundView = aView;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bView;
```

When the app loads, it loads the backgroundView correctly, but when I click on the cell the selectedBackgroundView no longer works in iOS7. The clicking selects the cell so that is working, but the selectBackgroundView just doesn't show.

Any suggestions? The only thing I can think is not use selectedBackgroundView and just add and remove subviews to the cell each time they are selected and unselected.

/// UPDATE ///

Put this in my cellForRowAtIndex and still does **NOT** work.

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // perfect color suggested by @mohamadHafez
    bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
```

//// UPDATE 2 ///////////

If I put this in my cellforRowAtIndex

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
    cell.backgroundView = nil;
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // perfect color suggested by @mohamadHafez
    bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;

    UIView *bgSColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    bgSColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(106.0/255.0) green:(201.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // perfect color suggested by @mohamadHafez
    bgSColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.backgroundView = bgSColorView;
```

Both the show cell.background as bgSColorView, but when I click the cell nothing happens (aka the selectedBackgroundView is NOT shown?  Why would the selectedBackgroundView not be promoted and shown?

/// UPDATE 3 ////
I put this in my setSelectin:animation: for my cell class (removed the stuff above).

```
 UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // perfect color suggested by @mohamadHafez
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;

UIView *bgSColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgSColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(106.0/255.0) green:(201.0/255.0) blue:(25.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // perfect color suggested by @mohamadHafez
bgSColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.backgroundView = bgSColorView;



[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
```

Now it appears correct, as I want it. But the second I click any cell BOOOM the background and selectionBackgroundView are removed instantly, vanished.

Comment: In 7 Apple did something with the cell background.  They slipped an opaque white layer in "above" the background, and it will only go away if you do setBackgroundColor on the cell *inside* cellForRowAtIndexPath (doing it in an XIB is not sufficient).  Not sure how this might affect background images, but you may need to set background color to clear.

Comment: Are you subclassing `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Yes it is being subclassed.  But I just changed it subclass UITableViewCell and still the same results.

Comment: Do you want also support edit mode (multiple cell selection) with cell customized background color?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this issue recently.

Found my problem was in my `.xib` I had the `selectionStyle` set to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone.

Once I set `self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;` my selectedBackgroundView started showing correctly.

So I did this.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;

    UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I can't get it to work in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: I just subclass UITableViewCell and override the setSelected:animated method like so:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_cell.png"];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
}
```

I just tried this in a different project and it didn't work .. Haha. Here's what I use now:

```
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
        {
             [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

            if (selected) {
                contentView.backgroundColor = SharedColors.Blue.ToUIColor ();
            } else {
                contentView.backgroundColor = SharedColors.Black.ToUIColor ();
            }
        }
```

Comment: But all that is setup when the tableview is built. I do all that, not each time the cell is selected. I shouldn't have to setup the selectedBackgroundView on each setSelection if I set it in the cellForRowAt... correct?

Comment: You're correct. I'm not sure why your cell.selectedBackgroundView = bView isn't working either so I just wanted to let you know of a workaround if you need it. Another possibility is to work with this delegate method: 

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:    (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

It gets called before the cell is drawn and could possibly be another good workaround.

Comment: sorry :P Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    var view = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.selectedBackgroundView = view


}
```